# NSComparisonResult failed same NSDate

Tags: ios

There is a object called Place. user can add place to favorite and also user can remove place from the favorite. once user added to the favorite I save date on the database. when user remove from the favorite I retrieve date from the db. and compare particular object with array of objects. but it gives NSOrderedAscending when comparing same object.

```
NSDate *date1 = obj1.date; // same date
NSDate *date2 = obj2.date; // same date
// compare using date
NSComparisonResult result = [date2 compare:date1];
```

any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: These dates may have different values of milliseconds?

Comment: Indeed; the debugger is rounding to the nearest second.

Comment: I would log the dates to the console, there may be more information that isn't being showed to you the way you are examining the dates.

Comment: Just saying: Your question is completely fine and reasonable. Don't worry about down votes.

Comment: Please update your question with your code as formatted text. Do not post images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare two dates are equivalent to the same second, then get the number of seconds since *some epoch* and round off the fractional part:

```
BOOL same = round([date1 timeIntervalSince1970]) ==
            round([date2 timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

Or convert to an integer:

```
BOOL same = (unsigned long)[date1 timeIntervalSince1970] ==
            (unsigned long)[date2 timeIntervalSince1970];
```

(you can also use `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` if you like, as well).

Comment: I suspect that there is a revenge downvoting going on.

Comment: @gnasher729 By who?  I haven't downvoted anyone here.

Comment: I have down voted an incorrect answer, and then someone down voted all the correct answers as well.

Comment: Just noticed this will do the job with seconds also.

Answer (score 1):

Try do this:

```
-(NSDate *)clearSecondsFromDate:(NSDate *)date 
{
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
timeInterval -= fmod(timeInterval, 60);
NSDate *clearDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:: timeInterval];
return clearDate;
}
```

Comment: @user2160335 Have you tested this code properly?  Do you want the seconds removed from the dates?

Comment: @trojanfoe It is fine with me. because first I compare the dates. if order is same then I compare with Id. anyway in my app cannot add two date at same second. so it won't be a problem.

Comment: @user2160335 You didn't make that clear in your question. And you say "my app cannot add two date at same second" (which I don't quite understand), but this code will assume any time within the same **minute** as being equal.

Comment: What I meant was, there is a place. user can add place to favorite and user can remove from favorite. when user add I store current date on the db. when user remove I retrieve the same date from the db. but when comparing its says NSOrderedAscending sometimes NSOrderedDecending. hope you can understand.

Answer (score -1):

NSDate doesn't just contain day and seconds, it has a resolution better than microseconds. Your NSDates are probably some fraction of a second apart. Try to log [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2].

So most likely your dates are just not the same. If you are sorting dates, and you want to have dates within the same second considered equal, take

```
double seconds1 = round ([date1 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
double seconds2 = round ([date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

which takes the time in a date and rounds it to the nearest second, and compare those values.